# read() on a pipe is not blocking

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux

I have following piece of code where I am using the pipe for two way read and write between parent and child process.

From what I have read, if I dont use O_NONBLOCK, the read should block until the data is written to the pipe from the other side.

However, I notice that the read on the parent side did not block. I know that, since I am debugging in gdb, I have put a sleep as a first statement inside the child.

Why did the read() by parent not block here? Also, is there anything else that I need to do to synchronize the read/write as below between the two processes?

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
}PayLoad;

PayLoad pl;
bool b = false;

int pipe_fds[2];


void p(int i, int j)
{
   pl.x = i;
   pl.y = j;

   pipe(pipe_fds);
   pid_t cpid = fork();

   if (cpid == 0) // child process
   {
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100)); // just for debugging
       close(pipe_fds[1]);
       read(pipe_fds[0], &pl, sizeof(Payload));
       //... do some processing on read data

       close(pipe_fds[0]);
       write(pipe_fds[1], &b, sizeof(bool));
       close(pipe_fds[1]);
   }
   else if (cpid > 0) // parent process
   {
       close(pipe_fds[0]);
       write(pipe_fds[1], &pl, sizeof(Payload));
       close(pipe_fds[1]);
       read(pipe_fds[0], &b, sizeof(bool));  <------ did not block!
       close(pipe_fds[0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: What does it return? Check the return value! And don't tag c, when it's c++ really.

Comment: Thank you. Just adding the code to check the return from read at the moment.

Comment: You close the descriptor before reading - indeed, decent error handling would have saved you some time - and will in the future.

Comment: May I ask! Why are you using c++ for this?

Comment: Thats because I am working on a cpp project and this code is inside a cpp file. Basically, I had a cpp thread that used to deadlock on an external library call. Hence putting the piece of code that used to hang into a process so that I could kill/restart the hanged process.

Comment: @ErkiA (and kadina)..Thank you. Indeed the descriptor is being closed. Reader first closes the write end of pipe before reading and similarly writer closes read end of the pipe before writing. However, what should I do for the scenario above, where, using the same pipe, the reader subsequently wants to write and hence the writer subsequently wants to read?

Comment: actually since pipes in unix are unidirectional, I will have to use two pipes in order to implement bidirectional communication between the parent and the child

Comment: @user2930006 : Yes. You need to use 2 pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If O_NONBLOCK is set, read() will return a -1 and set errno to [EAGAIN].

The real problem is you are closing the file descriptors before using them. For example, in the child process, you are closing pipe_fds[1] and you are using it for writing some value. In the parent process, you are closing pipe_fds[0] and you are using it for reading some value. Once the process closes the file descriptor, the process shouldn't use it for reading or writing. Usually pipe concept is one process (either parent or child) will write using one of file descriptors created by pipe and the other process (either parent or child) will read the data using another file descriptor.

Comment: Thank you Erki A and kadina. Indeed the descriptor is being closed. Reader first closes the write end of pipe before reading and similarly writer closes read end of the pipe before writing. However, what should I do for the scenario above, where, using the same pipe, the reader subsequently wants to write and hence the writer subsequently wants to read?

Comment: @user2930006 : You need to use 2 pipes.